# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'tail'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to create a new column 'S' in my df that it's calculated with other columns of the df like this:

'E' + 'I' - 'D' / **sum('D').tail(7) / 7**

where **sum(D).tail(7) / 7**  is the mean of the last seven values of 'D'

I tried:

`df['S'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['E'] + x['I'] -x['D']) / (sum(x['D'].tail(7))/7) if sum(x['D'].tail(7)) != 0 else np.inf, axis = 1)`

I'm using numpy instead of pandas because when I used pandas it gave me inf values.

I got:
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'tail'

Comment: please provide a minimal example of your input and the matching expected output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, when the `lambda x: ...` is used, what do you think will be the value of `x` each time it's called? Why? What will be the result of `x['D']`? Does that have a `.tail`? Why/how? Did you try to check, for example by using a debugger, or by converting the `lambda` to an ordinary function and inserting `print` calls? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre] and try to *isolate* the problem; we don't provide a debugging service.

Comment: Pandas dataframes and Series may have a `tail` method, but numpy arrays don't.  And single numbers certainly don't either.  When you get an `attribute` error, you either are asking for the wrong attribute, or have the wrong class of object.

Answer (score 0):

You're applying a func to each row/element (`float`) of the cols of the dataframe, hence the error.

IIUC your expected output, you can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Below, an example to show you the *logic* :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 9), columns=list("ABCDEFGHI"))
​
t = df["D"].tail(7).sum()
op1 = df["E"] + df["I"] - df["D"]
op2 = t / 7

df["S"] = np.where(t != 0, op1.div(op2), np.inf)
```

Output :

```
print(df)
​
          A         B         C  ...         H         I         S
0  0.768106  0.931050  0.118747  ...  0.055724  0.128807  0.540013
1  0.065579  0.546032  0.103620  ...  0.251604  0.181025  2.221726
2  0.839196  0.905637  0.395116  ...  0.171171  0.327523  0.074827
3  0.707141  0.015806  0.529460  ...  0.493165  0.142565  1.435263
4  0.665828  0.373126  0.305963  ...  0.166160  0.027367  1.036177
5  0.339683  0.306438  0.614405  ...  0.012405  0.057816  0.300547
6  0.916953  0.646930  0.928926  ...  0.079649  0.782347  2.924894
7  0.928679  0.587328  0.495888  ...  0.125690  0.863705  1.152783
8  0.515964  0.795475  0.898740  ...  0.984745  0.889819  2.848940
9  0.975653  0.397428  0.075647  ...  0.079495  0.559200  1.796947

[10 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I keep having this problem that instead of showing me the values of the column 'S' it says "inf". Actually, before all of this that I'm showing to you I tried: 
`df['S'] = (df['E'] + df['I'] - df['D']) / (sum(df['D'].tail(7))/7)`
and got the same result. Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Can't you share a reproducible example ?